# Change call type programmatically

Tags: android

How change a type of call programmatically using Content Providers? 
From missed call to received call?

Comment: Your question is way too vague. What are you trying to achieve? Can you provide some code samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the call log type from missed to received update that particular row from the database using update Query

```
String TYPE 

Call log type for incoming calls.
Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)

Call log type for missed calls.
Constant Value: 3 (0x00000003)
```